# How to use Actix actors to send message to another actor for websockets in Actix Web?

Tags: rust, websocket, actix-web, rust-actix

How to send a message to another actor?

```
pub struct MyWs {
}

impl Actor for MyWs {
    type Context = ws::WebsocketContext<Self>;
}

impl StreamHandler<Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>> for MyWs {
    fn handle(&mut self, msg: Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        match msg {
            Ok(ws::Message::Ping(msg)) => ctx.pong(&msg),
            Ok(ws::Message::Text(message)) => {

                //considering that here he sent the message to self
                ctx.text(message);

                //how to do something like this
                //find the actor by index (or uuid) and send text
                //actors[0].text(message);
                //
            },
            Ok(ws::Message::Binary(bin)) => ctx.binary(bin),
            Ok(ws::Message::Close(reason)) => ctx.close(reason),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}


#[get("/ws")]
pub async fn websocket(req: HttpRequest, stream: web::Payload,) -> actix_web::Result<HttpResponse> {
    let resp = ws::start(
        MyWs {},
        &req,
        stream,
    );
    return resp;
}
```

Could I make a hashMap of actors?

```
pub struct MyWs { sessions: HashMap<Uuid, Socket> }
```

and later

```
self.sessions.text(message)
```

I'm new to rust and I don't see a way to save the socket (the context or actor) to find it and send it messages.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check **the official example of a chat room app using actix web**.
https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/743af0ff1a9be6fb1cc13e6583108463c89ded4d/websockets/chat/src/main.rs

There are three key points:

1. create another server actor and get the address of it.

   `let server = server::ChatServer::new(app_state.clone()).start();`
2. set the server actor's address as application data of HttpServer.

   ```
   HttpServer::new(move || {
       App::new()
           .data(app_state.clone())
           // copy server actor's address into app
           .data(server.clone())
           .service(web::resource("/").route(web::get().to(|| {
               HttpResponse::Found()
                   .header("LOCATION", "/static/websocket.html")
                   .finish()
           })))
           .route("/count/", web::get().to(get_count))
           // websocket
           .service(web::resource("/ws/").to(chat_route))
           // static resources
           .service(fs::Files::new("/static/", "static/"))
   })
   .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
   .run()
   .await
   ```
3. store the address while starting websocket actor in function `chat_route`. And then you could use the address to send messages whenever you want

```
/// Entry point for our websocket route
async fn chat_route(
    req: HttpRequest,
    stream: web::Payload,
    srv: web::Data<Addr<server::ChatServer>>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    ws::start(
        WsChatSession {
            id: 0,
            hb: Instant::now(),
            room: "Main".to_owned(),
            name: None,
            addr: srv.get_ref().clone(),
        },
        &req,
        stream,
    )
}
```